# ISO on DVD differing across platforms?

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image, comparison, windows-8-preview

I have the 32-bit ISO of the Windows 8 Consumer Preview and I burned it to a DVD (using Nero Express on Windows XP) to install in VirtualBox on my other computer (running Fedora 15).

The problem is, when I try to boot from the ISO in VirtualBox on my Linux computer it gives and error and won't boot.

Interestingly, when I open the ISO in Fedora's Archive Manager, it shows it as occupying 2.5GB, but only containing a blank text file called `README.TXT`; however, when I open it using 7zip on Windows it shows it as having quite a lot of files.

Why is the data differing between platforms? And if the ISO isn't corrupted, why isn't it booting?

EDIT: BTW, the error I get when I try to boot in VirtualBox is the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/396053/error-0xc0000260-when-installing-windows-8-consumer-preview-on-an-old-laptop)

EDIT #2: Turns out Windows 8 requires NX; once I enabled it it booted just fine.

Comment: Did you read the `README.TXT`? I think I can guess what's going on, and if I'm correct, I'm nearly 100% sure the ReadMe also tells you what's going on. :P

Comment: @Mehrdad README.TXT is completely blank

Comment: *> Why is the data differing between platforms? And if the ISO isn't corrupted, why isn't it booting?* Use a tool like [IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/) or [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to get more detailed information about the ISO. With IsoBuster, you can view the file-systems (and the files they contain) that are present in the image which will more thank likely explain what is happening: different tools look at/see the image differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was Fedora's Archive Manager causing the problem, I opened the ISO using PeaZip and it showed all the files.

I still don't know why that particular ISO was not opening right with the Archive Manager; I'm pretty sure I was able to open other ISOs with it before

Answer (score 3):

You have two separate issues that have nothing to do with each other.

Your installation problem most likely has to do with you using a virtualization product that doesn't support Windows 8 because of the version or the way it's configured. You don't mention your CPU, but VT-x technology is required to support Windows 8 on VirtualBox. If you disabled it in the BIOS or your CPU doesn't support it, that's your problem. Make sure to select Windows 7 as the machine type and give it at least 1GB of RAM. Use VDI, enable APIC, enable PAE/NX, enable VT-x and nested paging. Then it should install.

Your other issue (some tools showing the files on the DVD and some not) is just lack of support for [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disc_Format) on older tools. It doesn't indicate anything wrong with the disk.

Comment: Thanks; my CPU does support VT-x, and it is enabled in the BIOS; I had issues with that not being enabled before so I always check that. See the EDIT #2; it was NX not being enabled that was preventing it from booting. However, I know that UDF works with the tools that I have; because I needed to open a UDF disk before and it worked just fine