# Error code 0xc0000260 while starting Windows 8 in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error 0xc0000260 when installing Windows 8 Consumer Preview on an old laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/396053/error-0xc0000260-when-installing-windows-8-consumer-preview-on-an-old-laptop)

While installing Windows 8 on VirtualBox I got  a strange error in the final step.

> Error code 0xc0000260 Your PC needs to be repaired

It tells me to Press Enter to check again or to Press F8 to use an alternate boot. Tried doing both but of no use.

How to proceed further ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Click Settings → System → Processor
2. Check Enable PAE/NX box.
3. Click OK
4. Restart the virtual machine.

Should work now!